# Requirement for starting Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I decided to learn Flutter .to get started on Flutter, do I need to learn dort language in-depth or advanced level, or is it enough at an intermediate level?

Comment: It depends on how in depth you want to code in Flutter. Flutter uses Dart, so learn Dart to the same extent that you want to learn Flutter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the beginning you can start flutter even with intermediate level of Dart knowledge and over time, you will eventually learn the advance features of Dart while developing apps and also, Dart is one of the easiest language to learn.

So I recommend you to start flutter with basic Dart knowledge and leave everything else on time.